# Letter - Number style list in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I need a list formatted like this:

```
A. Top level item
   1. number 1
   2. number 2
B. Second top-level
   1. number 2
```

How do I do that? List of formats for list has only number-letter options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the list formatting from the Format menu.

1. Choose your list style (Capital letters)
2. Get into your second tier.
3. Click Format > Lists > List Options
4. Select "1" for numeric bullets.

The list will now add capital letters at the top level and numbers at level 2. You can do this independently at each indentation level.